# API calls limit for Office365 REST APIs (Sharepoint/OneDrive)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, onedrive-for-business

I want to know the limit for API calls per minute/hour for Office365 REST APIs (Sharepoint/OneDrive).

Is there any documentation for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are now throttling limits for Office 365 REST APIs. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn889829.aspx

Throttling can be triggered if you exceed 1 request per second continuously. You will receive a HTTP status code 429 ("Too many requests") if this happens. For your average app you are unlikely to trigger throttling. But for intensive operations you should consider handling the 429 status code and use a "backing off" algorithm like the one described in the MSDN article.

Comment: Also, what about this API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx ?

Comment: Good question. Not sure if throttling applies to SharePoint apps yet. My understanding is that in due course throttling will be applied to all APIs. Note that throttling has only been implemented recently hence why you haven't found any info on it :)

Comment: One more question, if I am an Admin (a Site Admin) on OneDrive for 2 tenant users and I try to access their data using Admin's credentials, then will this access go under Admin's access limit? (since I assume this throttling you mentioned is per user) or will it be marked for the target user?

So what I'm saying is that suppose the limit is 100 calls per user & I access 2 tenant users OneDrive data as Admin. I make 20 calls to get data for user1 and 20 calls for user 2. Will the call limit for Admin be 60 now? or will it mark this for users themselves (user1,2 remaining limit would be 80 each)