# What are the alternatives to authenticate in SharePoint beyond AD to use the Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, ad, ms-project, nodejs

I am trying to consume via Rest the Ms Project API from a Node client, I was searching and found that it's possible to get an access token from the ACS (Azure Access Control) and use this in the rest requests, well, if I am logged in with email and password in the SharePoint, I do can get data from MsProject listed in XMl or Json on the browser, but I can't figure out how to do the api authentication just with email and password. I was wondering if there is any other way to get an access token to my Ms Project or other services in my SharePoint other than AD to authenticate in the SharePoint via API? if so, how could I?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint Online and username + password authentication, you can try using my [sp-request](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request) module. It's for SharePoint primarily, however, works for MS Project as well.

Comment: do you know where in the docs can I find the API limit usage?

Comment: Which kind of limits do you mean?

Comment: max number of requests per time or requests per resource by user, things like that, well I found a helpful answer ['here'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116639/api-calls-limit-for-office365-rest-apis-sharepoint-onedrive), thanks for your time...  :)